# merge different update sites into one in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have 2 different update sites (from 2 different clients). Is it possible to combine these 2 update sites into single one using eclipse mechanism, so that i can give single url/location in the Install Software menu and it shows the both update sites contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a so called composite repository. To create such a repository you can use a special p2 ant call, e.g.

```
<p2.composite.repository>
  <repository location="file:/myDestination" name="A new repository" kind="M" />
  <add>
    <repository location="http://aSource/" kind="M" />
  </add>
</p2.composite.repository>
```

For further information see the [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_%28new%29)

Comment: how shall i call this task from eclipse environment?

Comment: I got it: java -jar <Eclipse-HOME>\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -f <Path to ant xml>